# Smooth animation for rgb led arduino

Tags: c, arduino, rgb, hsv

I'm trying to make a smooth transition with arduino, it receives rgb values from serial correctly, but it seems to don't reach the target color because it oscillates between different values. I'm using this library to convert in hsv [RGBConverter](https://github.com/ratkins/RGBConverter/blob/master/RGBConverter.cpp). I tried to convert rgb value in hsv and to change gradually hsv values. This is my code:

```
RGBConverter converter = RGBConverter();
my_color cur_color;
void setup() {

  pinMode(RED_LED, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(GREEN_LED, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(BLUE_LED, OUTPUT); 
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  cur_color={0,0,0};

  }

void loop() {                  
      my_color final={Serial.read(),Serial.read(),Serial.read()};
      double hsv[3];
      converter.rgbToHsv(final.red,final.green,final.blue,hsv);
      reach_color(&cur_color,hsv);                
  }
```

Color is a struct that contains three byte values named red, green and blue

This is the  reach_color method

```
void reach_color(struct color *start, double hsv_final[]){
  double hsv[3];
  byte rgb[3];

  while(true){
    converter.rgbToHsv(start->red,start->green,start->blue,hsv);
    if ( hsv[0] >hsv_final[0]&&hsv[0]>0 ) hsv[0] -= 0.01;
    else if(hsv[0]<hsv_final[0]&&hsv[0]<1) hsv[0]+= 0.01;
    else if(hsv[1]>hsv_final[1]&&hsv[1]>0) hsv[1]-= 0.01;
    else if(hsv[1]<hsv_final[1]&&hsv[1]<1) hsv[1]+= 0.01;
    else if(hsv[2]>hsv_final[2]&&hsv[2]>0) hsv[2]-= 0.01;
    else if(hsv[2]<hsv_final[2]&&hsv[2]<1) hsv[2]+= 0.01;
    else return;

    converter.hsvToRgb(hsv[0],hsv[1], hsv[2], rgb);
    start->red=rgb[0];
    start->green=rgb[1];
    start->blue=rgb[2];
    display_color(*start);
    delay(30);
    }
}
```

and this is display  method

```
void display_color(struct color c){
analogWrite(GREEN_LED, c.green);  
analogWrite(BLUE_LED, c.blue);  
analogWrite(RED_LED, c.red); 
}
```

I need to gradually move from current color to final color, but while never goes in the else clause and current color oscillates between different values, does anyone know where is the error?
Thank you all in advance for the help

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. Is there a question here?

Comment: You are right, I was not clear, I'm editing the main post

Comment: Probably, it oscilates because your are reading without being sure that there is data in buffer... Remember that typical structure is `if(Serial.available()){/*READ SERIAL AND PROCESS IT*/}`

Comment: Thank you, surely code is more correct now, but the problem persists, I tried to print on serial monitor rgb values received on serial and their hsv conversion, and are both correct. I think that my error is inside the algorithm reach_color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that my error is inside the algorithm reach_color

Right. Consider e. g. `hsv[0]` is 0.005 and `hsv_final[0]` is 0; the line

```
    if ( hsv[0] >hsv_final[0]&&hsv[0]>0 ) hsv[0] -= 0.01;
```

will set `hsv[0]` to −0.005 (which is outside the range [0, 1] assumed by `hsvToRgb()`, whatever that does with it). In the next loop cycle, the line

```
    else if(hsv[0]<hsv_final[0]&&hsv[0]<1) hsv[0]+= 0.01;
```

will set `hsv[0]` to +0.005 anew - and so it goes on oscillating. In general, the repeated addition or subtraction of 0.01 is unlikely to yield exactly the same value that `rgbToHsv()` returned.
Also you should be aware that 0.01 like most decimal fractions cannot be exactly represented in a `double` (it results in approximately 0.01000000000000000021).
Moreover, the repeated calling of `rgbToHsv()` in the loop, recalculating `hsv[]` values based on the previous `rgb[]` values, makes the algorithm's behavior more difficult to predict.

So, we have to allow for a tolerance of the HSV values for the comparisons, and better use only the `hsv[]` values for the iteration:

```
void reach_color(struct color *start, double hsv_final[])
{
  double hsv[3];
  byte rgb[3];

  converter.rgbToHsv(start->red, start->green, start->blue, hsv);
  while (true)
  {
         if (hsv[0] - 0.01 >= hsv_final[0]) hsv[0] -= 0.01;
    else if (hsv[0] + 0.01 <= hsv_final[0]) hsv[0] += 0.01;
    else if (hsv[1] - 0.01 >= hsv_final[1]) hsv[1] -= 0.01;
    else if (hsv[1] + 0.01 <= hsv_final[1]) hsv[1] += 0.01;
    else if (hsv[2] - 0.01 >= hsv_final[2]) hsv[2] -= 0.01;
    else if (hsv[2] + 0.01 <= hsv_final[2]) hsv[2] += 0.01;
    else return;

    converter.hsvToRgb(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2], rgb);
    start->red   = rgb[0];
    start->green = rgb[1];
    start->blue  = rgb[2];
    display_color(*start);
    delay(30);
  }
}
```